# How can I authorize a property to be accessed by Admin users only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How can I allow a property to be accessed by "Admin" users only?

I have a class "Customer" like this:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
```

}

I have a UsersAPIController which has a GetCustomers method that retrieves all the Customers data from the database using EF.

```
public class CustomersAPIController : ApiController
    {
    // GET: api/CustomersAPI
        public IQueryable<User> GetCustomers()
        {
            return db.Customers;
        }
}
```

I want the GetCustomers method to reurn the "SSN" property of the Customers class only when the application user accessing the method has "Admin" role. I was able to get the required result by using select statement to return the "SSN" property for Admin users in the "GetCustomers" method. However, this will require a lot of coding since the Customer data is used in multiple places in the application.

Is it possible to something like this:

```
//Allow Admin user access only
[AdminUserOnly]
public string SSN { get; set; }
```

So that the data returned contains the SSN property only for Admin user access?

Comment: you have to authorize by role check this link http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/roles.html

Comment: @Adriano Repetti how is that a duplicate? There is no mention of roles in the original question, only how to remove a field.

Comment: No sorry, time to have a break. No JSON involved. Reopened, thanks

Comment: @rashfmmnb I do not to authorize the access to the GetCustomers method in controller for Admin role only because all roles should have access to the method but not all the fields returned by the method.

Answer (score 2):

If you are returning an object that has a public property, you will not be able to restrict access to the property apart from not setting the value if non-admin. Once you have passed the object to the consumer, I do not believe you can do anything further.

I would look at checking the for the admin authorization in `GetCustomers` and populating the property if they do have access. Alternatively, you could populate all values and check for the admin rights and empty them accordingly.

Comment: Since the **GetCustomers** method can be accessed by all roles, I do not want to check the admin authorization in the method.

Comment: @kalno12 why not? It's exactly what you should do. Check caller roles and wipe that property if he is not allowed to see it.